# listview and slidingdrawer gives error

Tags: android, listview, dimensions, slidingdrawer

I have this problem for 2 days and I can't find any solution for it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/presentation_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>

<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/presentation_list"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/content_imageview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```

I have this pretty simple layout with a `listview` and a `slidingdrawer` that I want to come over the `listview`. When I open my `activity` with no info, it shows perfect with no exception of any kind.

But when there is an item in my `listview`, my `slidingdrawer` gives an exception of the kind.

```
   AndroidRuntime(4722): java.lang.RuntimeException: SlidingDrawer cannot have UNSPECIFIED dimensions
```

I've searched for this many times for a solution but NONE work for me.

Is there anyone with a brilliant breakthrough for me? It is very much appreciated!

Comment: My layout works now, updated my question to match layout.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought on this....What happens if you define exact dimensions for the content_imageview inside you sliding drawer.

From viewing your code and the Android documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html this would appear to be the only difference.

Might be worth reading up on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html to better understand `UNSPECIFIED` and how it is used in the MeasureSpec.

Also look at specifying set dimensions for the handle component.

Regarding the layout you have defined are you better specifying the sliding drawer to alignParentBottom and aligning the list view above the sliding drawer. On a short list your sliding drawer is going to sit half way up the layout...

Answer (score 0):

Give your `android:layout_height` in relative layout a number(eg. 600 dip). When sliding drawer layout height is `match_parent`, it will follow along relative layout whose layout height is `fill_parent`, this will cause your sliding drawer to go infinite.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to define `SlidingDrawer` inside `LinearLayout` not the other way round.

Comment: No that's not it, that linearlayout represents my content of the slidingdrawer.